# Why isn't the Cantor set a discrete topology?

Tags: general-topology

It is well known that Cantor set $C$ contains no intervals, hence for every $p,q\in C$ such that (without loss of generality) $p<q$, there exists $r\in \mathbb{R}\setminus C$ such that $p<r<q$. You can always find a point between two different points in $C$ that is not in $C$, since $C$ is disconnected.

Thus for each point $p\in C$, there exits and open interval $(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $C\cap (a,b)=\{p\}$. So every singleton in $C$ is an open set.

It easily follows that $C$ must be a discrete topology.

But I keep hearing that $C$ is NOT a discrete topology, because it is homeomorphic to an infinite product space of discrete spaces consisting of $\{0,1\}$. My argument would be that they are BOTH discrete. Am I wrong?

Comment: Your second paragraph is false. Why do you think there should exist an open interval $(a,b)$ with $C\cap(a,b)=\{p\}$? That does not follow from the lack of intervals. (In fact, there is _no_ point $p\in C$ for which that is true.)

Comment: "You can always find a point between two different points in $C$ that is not in $C$, since $C$ is disconnected."
This should be:
"[...], since $C$ is totally disconnected."

The set $S = (0, 1) \cup (1, 2)$ is also disconnected but there is no such point for $\frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4} \in S$.

Comment: For every $p,q\in\mathbb Q$, there exists $r\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ such that $p<q<r$. Yet you wouldn't try to claim that therefore for each $p\in\mathbb Q$, there exists an open interval $(a,b)\subset\mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb Q\cap(a,b)=\{p\}$. The same principle applies here.

Comment: For one thing, a set is not a topology.

Comment: The members of $C$ are the members of $[0,1$] that can be represented in base $3$ without using the digit $1.$ For example $1=0.\overline 2$ and $2/3=0.2\overline  0$ and $\frac {3}{4}=0.\overline {20}.$

Answer (score 8):

This is not true: For every $p$, $\exists\ a,b$ such that $C \cap (a,b) = \{p\}$.

For example, $\frac 14 \in C$. In fact, there exists a non-constant sequence of endpoints in $C$ that converges to $\frac 14$. That sequence is: $$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{3^{2k}} \quad \implies \quad a_n \to \frac{1}{4}$$

This shows that $C$ does not have the discrete topology, because it has a limit point.

Comment: Nice simple proof!

Comment: But then this would contradicts the fact that $C$ contains no interval?

Comment: @SidCaroline No, it would not contradict that. For example, $\mathbb Q$ contains no interval, but it has limit points.

Comment: But then how could it be homeomorphic to the infinite product of $\{0,1\}$? Each $\{0,1\}$ is discrete, so the infinite product must also be discrete, because if $\pi_k$ is the kth projection, then $\pi_k$ maps every singleton in the infinite product space to an open set in $\{0,1\}$, namely $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$?

Comment: @SidCaroline An element of the Cantor set is of the form $\frac{2a_1}{3} + \frac{2a_2}{3^2}+\frac{2a_3}{3^3} +\frac{2a_4}{3^4}+\cdots$, where $a_i$'s are either $0$ or $1$. Now, you can map this element in the Cantor set to $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,dots) \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$. Observe that this is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @SidCaroline The fact that the image of a set (here a singleton) is open under the projections, doesn't make this set open in the product topology. The open sets there are the smallest collection  of subsets that make all projections continuous. For this we only need the sets $\pi_k^{-1}[\{0\}] $ and $\pi_k^{-1}[\{1\}]$ to be open.

Comment: This is a superb example, with $\frac14=.0202020\dots_3$. But wouldn’t the ternary expansion of any Cantor number $z$ show at a glance that $z$ was the limit of other Cantor numbers, namely the ones gotten by cutting off the ternary expansion of $z$ at various lengths?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the confusing thing about infinite products: The product topology on an $\prod A_i$ has as a subbasis (a collection of sets from which one can obtain any open set from finite intersection and arbitrary union) things of the form $\prod U_i$, where $U_i$ is open in $A_i$, and for all but one $i$, $U_i=A_i$.
So the topology is not discrete, as any open set containing the origin contains every point that agrees with the origin except on some finite set of coordinates.
The box topology is obtained by allowing $U_i$ to be an arbitrary open set for every $A_i$. This gives much finer topologies (stronger to analysts, weaker to topologists — because it's harder for sequences to converge, but easier for sets to be open).
For example, the function $f: \Bbb R\to\Bbb R^\infty$ defined by $f(x) = (x,x,x,\ldots)$ is continuous if $\Bbb R^\infty$ is given the product topology, but is horrendously discontinuous if it is given the box topology, as in the box topology, the set $\prod\limits_i(-\frac1i,\frac1i)$ is an open neighborhood of $f(0)$, but its preimage is just $\{0\}$.